# How to substract 2 days in MySQL excluding weekends

Tags: mysql

I want to substract 2 days from a date in MySQL without taking into account weekends,

So if my date is 11-28-13 I want to obtain 11-26-13

In the case the current date is 11-25-13 (monday) I want to obtain 11-21-13

Comment: What output do you need when current date is Sunday?

Comment: I solved it, this is what I did

Comment: SELECT
DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL
CASE
WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())=1 THEN 3
WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())=2 THEN 4
WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())=3 THEN 4
WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())=4 THEN 1
WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())=5 THEN 1
WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())=6 THEN 1
WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())=7 THEN 2
END
DAY)

Comment: Have you tested that? You are subtracting 1 day for Thursday and Friday, but in the question you wish to subtract 2 days.